# Initializing reference variables with the conditional if else operator

Tags: c++, reference, conditional-operator

The following C++ is invalid because reference variables require initializers:

```
int& a; // illegal
if (isfive) {
  a = 5;
} else {
  a = 4;
}
```

However, MSVC seems to think this is okay:

```
int& a = isfive ? 5 : 4;
```

This implies to me that MSVC is actually treating the conditional operator like a single expression and not expanding it into an if-else statement.

Is it always valid C++ to initialize a reference using the conditional operator?

Comment: I'm curious what happens if you try to compare it on an assembly level...

Comment: How can you compare on an assemly level code that compiles and code that doesn't?

Comment: What does it do? Please post assembly! :-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin: Unfortunately in Visual C++ this illegal code is accepted.  (The second form).

Comment: @BenVoigt, not every illegal code, just one of the two :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin: So what we really have is code that doesn't compile and more code that doesn't compile, and I agree it's really hard to compare the assembly :)

Comment: @krynr, you mean the second? References temporary, I think. I wonder how short-lived... I actually don't think the OP meant two constants, anyway, he was probably talking about conditionals and came up with unfortunate example.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin: I just hoped to find the addresses of 4 and 5. :-) But as you said... Not funny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSVC has a non-standard "extension".  What it means is that it allows broken code.  There's a good reason this is prohibited.

Note also that

```
int& a = 5;
```

is not legal in Standard C++ either.

In general, though, it is legal to initialize a `const` reference with any expression which can be converted to the right type (including use of the conditional operator).  And it is legal to initialize a non-`const` reference with an lvalue of the right type, which the conditional operator yields under certain conditions.

Comment: Well what do you know, asking this question solved a problem I didn't even know I had. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

The ternary operator does not expand to an `if-else` construct (not according to the language, the implementation might generate equivalent binaries, but at the language level they are different). So the following code is valid:

```
int four = 4, five = 5;
int& r = condition? four : five;
```

The original example in the question depends on a Microsoft extension that (incorrectly) allows binding a non-const reference to an rvalue expression.

Comment: Love it. Not sure why I didn't think of this. I wrote a function etc.. etc..

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted does not compile with VC++ 2010:

Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int &'

Changing the line to:

```
const int& a = isfive ? 5 : 4;
```

makes it compile.

Comment: I assume you are using the `/Za` (disable language extensions) option?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Nope. It seems that the issue is fixed: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/szywdw8k

Comment: I wonder what that's doing on TechNet instead of MSDN.  There are still some related bugs, but glad to see the most typical case is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The conditional operator is an expression, not a statement. It is perfectly fine to initialise a reference like that. It's a little like initialising a reference by calling a function.

Note that your reference needs to be `const` if you bind it to temporaries (a rule which MSVC++ stupidly ignores).

Comment: *It is prefectly fine to initialise a reference like that* only if we ignore the fact that you cannot bind a non-const reference to an rvalue... (i.e. `const int& r = isfive? 4 : 5;` is fine, but `int& r = isfive? 4 : 5;` is not)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas yeah, I added a note about that a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

**Pointer + reference technique**

It does feel like a limitation of the C++ language that could be overcome with a new language feature.

The most efficient option I can see until then (in case you are doing more in the if else than just setting the reference, in which case you could use the ternary operator `?`) is to use a pointer, and then set the reference to the pointer to avoid doing multiple dereferences when using the variable later on when every time you use the variable:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    (void)argv;
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int *ptr;
    if (argc > 1) {
        ptr = &x;
    } else {
        ptr = &y;
    }
    // One pointer dereference here, I don't see how to get rid of this.
    int &z = *ptr;
    // No pointer dereference on any of the below usages.
    z = 3;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
    std::cout << z << std::endl;
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
```

run:

```
./main.out
```

output:

```
1
3
3
```

run again:

```
./main.out a
```

output:

```
3
2
3
```

If the if condition is known at compile time however, you could of course use the preprocessor or better, C++17 `if constexpr`: [if / else at compile time in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160765/if-else-at-compile-time-in-c/54647315#54647315)

Related: [Declare a reference and initialize later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882995/declare-a-reference-and-initialize-later/29311535#29311535)

Comment: You can get rid of pointer/dereferencing by lambda: `auto& ref = [&]() -> int& { if (cond) return x; return y;}();`

Answer (score 1):

it is not OK

```
int& a = isfive ? 5 : 4;
```

unless you declare the reference "a" as a `const`.

Answer (score 0):

It is operator, part of the expression, not a statement. And you can't leave reference uninitialized even for a short while ;-)