# Does the compiler remove if statements where the condition is always false?

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++11, compiler-optimization, c++-templates

I know some metaprogramming techniques in C++ to compute constants at compile-time. Most of the time branching in metafunctions is done through the ternary operators which can be evaluated at compile-time on the contrary of standard if/else.

But regarding this kind of function:

```
template <unsigned int N>
void f()
{
    if (N == 0) {
        // Some computations here
    } else if (N <= 42) {
        // Some computations here
    } else {
        // Some computations here
    }
}
```

What will the compiler do (assuming `-O3`) ?
The compiler knows that `f<0>()` will always branch on the first case, `f<32>()` will always branch on the second case, and `f<64>()` will always branch on the third case.

Will the compiler remove branches that will always be `false` ? Will it directly branch to the only valid case ?

Comment: Yes, a modern compiler will remove useless branches.

Comment: that said ... if you want to _guarantee_ that, then how about simply using _template specialization_ instead and say: `template <...> void f<0>( /* computation for 0 */ }` etc. to make it absolutely, unambiguously, compiler-independently clear what you want ?

Comment: Strongly related: [if / else at compile time in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160765/if-else-at-compile-time-in-c?rq=3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The optimizer will remove the branch and the code in the unused branches, but beware: the compiler needs to process the function before the optimizer even gets a chance to look at the code, which means that all branches must be valid (compilable) for all values of `N`.

For example, if the second branch contained:

```
} else if (N <= 42) {
   char data[50 - N];
// other code
```

The compiler will fail to instantiate the template for `N >= 50` even though the branch will be removed by the optimizer.

Answer (score 2):

I typed the following into http://gcc.godbolt.org/, which is an online compiler that displays the generated assembly. You can use your own compiler with whatever switch it supports to output assembly instead.

```
volatile int i;

template <unsigned int N>
void f()
{
    if (N == 0) {
        i = 1;
    } else if (N <= 42) {
        i = 2;
    } else {
        i = 3;
    }
}

template void f<0>();
template void f<10>();
template void f<100>();
```

Here's the assembly I got

```
void f<0u>():                           # @void f<0u>()
    movl    $1, i
    ret

void f<10u>():                          # @void f<10u>()
    movl    $2, i
    ret

void f<100u>():                         # @void f<100u>()
    movl    $3, i
    ret

i:
    .long   0                       # 0x0
```

As you can see, each instantiation has had all the dead code removed.

In fact, this code was generated with optimization disabled; the compiler I used (clang) does not generate instructions for dead code in the first place. Other compilers may behave differently. You'll have to test the behavior of your own compiler yourself.

Comment: Agree on the findings ... but also, you _could_ just force this no matter the compiler's choices if you specialize ?