# Implementing a compile-time "static-if" logic for different string types in a container

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, containers, compile-time

I'd like to write a function template that operates on a container of strings, for example a `std::vector`.

I'd like to support both `CString` and `std::wstring` with the same template function.

The problem is that `CString` and wstring have different interfaces, for example to get the "length" of a `CString`, you call the `GetLength()` method, instead for wstring you call `size()` or `length()`.

If we had a *"static if"* feature in C++, I could write something like:

```
template <typename ContainerOfStrings>
void DoSomething(const ContainerOfStrings& strings)
{
    for (const auto & s : strings)
    {
        static_if(strings::value_type is CString) 
        {
            // Use the CString interface
        }
        static_else_if(strings::value_type is wstring)
        {   
            // Use the wstring interface
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some template programming technique to achieve this goal with currently available C++11/14 tools?

**PS**
I know it's possible to write a couple of `DoSomething()` overloads with `vector<CString>` and `vector<wstring>`, but that's not the point of the question.
Moreover, I'd like this function template to work for any container on which you can iterate using a range-for loop.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDwhfjBPKv8 good lightning talk on the subject from meeting c++ 2015

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if / else at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160765/if-else-at-compile-time) + check string underlying type at compile time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename F>
auto static_if(std::true_type, T t, F f) { return t; }

template <typename T, typename F>
auto static_if(std::false_type, T t, F f) { return f; }

template <bool B, typename T, typename F>
auto static_if(T t, F f) { return static_if(std::integral_constant<bool, B>{}, t, f); }

template <bool B, typename T>
auto static_if(T t) { return static_if(std::integral_constant<bool, B>{}, t, [](auto&&...){}); }
```

Test:

```
template <typename ContainerOfStrings>
void DoSomething(const ContainerOfStrings& strings)
{
    for (const auto & s : strings)
    {
        static_if<std::is_same<typename ContainerOfStrings::value_type, CString>{}>
        ([&](auto& ss)
        {
            // Use the CString interface
            ss.GetLength();
        })(s);

        static_if<std::is_same<typename ContainerOfStrings::value_type, wstring>{}>
        ([&](auto& ss)
        {
            // Use the wstring interface
            ss.size();
        })(s);
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1261da35b6ccb7a)

Comment: Since I can mark only one answer, I'm choosing this because it resembles the structure of a "static if". However, when possible, I prefer simpler solutions like traits or function overloads. Thanks for sharing your code.

Comment: It seems like the lambda still has to compile and be passed to the appropriate static_if function, so if this compiles it is probably because the compiler optimizes away the unused parameter in the top two definitions. It should still be ill-formed, however, unless I'm missing something...

Comment: @piotr-skotnicki why this does not work with gcc6 and gcc@7 on mac os?

Comment: problem is for bug on gcc that reported on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64095

Answer (score 6):

You could provide function overloads that do what you need:

```
size_t getSize(const std::string& str)
{
    return str.size();
}

size_t getSize(const CString& str)
{
    return str.GetLength();
}

template <typename ContainerOfStrings>
void DoSomething(const ContainerOfStrings& strings)
{
    for (const auto & s : strings)
    {
        ...
        auto size = getSize(s);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One common way to solve this is to extract the required interface out into a trait class. Something like this:

```
template <class S>
struct StringTraits
{
  static size_t size(const S &s) { return s.size(); }
  // More functions here
};


template <typename ContainerOfStrings>
void DoSomething(const ContainerOfStrings& strings)
{
    for (const auto & s : strings)
    {
      auto len = StringTraits<typename std::decay<decltype(s)>::type>::size(s);
    }
}


// Anyone can add their own specialisation of the traits, such as:

template <>
struct StringTraits<CString>
{
  static size_t size(const CString &s) { return s.GetLength(); }
  // More functions here
};
```

Of course, you can then go fancy and change the function itself to allow trait selection in addition to the type-based selection:

```
template <class ContainerOfStrings, class Traits = StringTraits<typename ContainerOfString::value_type>>
void DoSomething(const ContainerOfStrings& strings)
```

Comment: I believe `StringTraits<decltype(s)>` won't work correctly inside the range for loop, considering the `const auto& s` iteration (`for (const auto & s : strings) ...`). Using the container's `value_type` instead is a better alternative.

Comment: @Mr.C64 `value_type` need not exist. I've fixed the `decltype` use.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one with a pretty syntax.

The goal is to get rid of the extra `()`s in @Piotr's solution.

Lots of boilerplate:

```
template<bool b>
struct static_if_t {};
template<bool b>
struct static_else_if_t {};

struct static_unsolved_t {};

template<class Op>
struct static_solved_t {
  Op value;
  template<class...Ts>
  constexpr
  decltype(auto) operator()(Ts&&...ts) {
    return value(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
  template<class Rhs>
  constexpr
  static_solved_t operator->*(Rhs&&)&&{
    return std::move(*this);
  }
};
template<class F>
constexpr
static_solved_t<std::decay_t<F>> static_solved(F&& f) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}

template<class F>
constexpr
auto operator->*(static_if_t<true>, F&& f) {
  return static_solved(std::forward<F>(f));
}
template<class F>
constexpr
static_unsolved_t operator->*(static_if_t<false>, F&&) {
  return {};
}
constexpr
static_if_t<true> operator->*(static_unsolved_t, static_else_if_t<true>) {
  return {};
}
constexpr
static_unsolved_t operator->*(static_unsolved_t, static_else_if_t<false>) {
  return {};
}

template<bool b>
constexpr static_if_t<b> static_if{};

template<bool b>
constexpr static_else_if_t<b> static_else_if{};

constexpr static_else_if_t<true> static_else{};
```

Here is what it looks like at point of use:

```
template <typename ContainerOfStrings>
void DoSomething(const ContainerOfStrings& strings) {
  for (const auto & s : strings)
  {
    auto op = 
    static_if<std::is_same<typename ContainerOfStrings::value_type,CString>{}>->*
    [&](auto&& s){
        // Use the CString interface
    }
    ->*static_else_if<std::is_same<typename ContainerOfStrings::value_type, std::cstring>{}>->*
    [&](auto&& s){   
        // Use the wstring interface
    };
    op(s); // fails to compile if both of the above tests fail
  }
}
```

with an unlimited chain of `static_else_if`s supported.

It does not prevent you from doing an unlimited chain of `static_else` (`static_else` in the above is just an alias for `static_else_if<true>`).

Answer (score 3):

You could provide two overloads for getting the length:

```
template<typename T>
std::size_t getLength(T const &str)
{
    return str.size();
}

std::size_t getLength(CString const &str)
{
  return str.GetLength();
}
```