# How to restrict template class to only specific specializations with type aliases

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, anonymous-class

What I aim to achieve is to have a templated Wrapper class with various aliases. Here is a simplified preview:

```
template < typename Type >
class Wrapper {
public:
   Wrapper(Type* resource) : ptr(resource) {}
   ~Wrapper() { free(ptr); }

private:
   Type* ptr;
}

void free(SDL_Window* ptr) { SDL_DestroyWindow(ptr); }
void free(SDL_Renderer* ptr) { SDL_DestroyRenderer(ptr); }

using Window = Wrapper<SDL_Window>;
using Renderer = Wrapper<SDL_Renderer>;
```

I would like to allow creation of only these aliased instances of Wrapper class. One of the reasons, is that this being wrapper to a SDL resource pointers, it has different memory freeing functions depending on type of the pointer.

Best scenario I would like to achieve would be to make Wrapper class not visible outside the usage of aliases I create. Maybe there is a solution using anonymous namespace, but thaw would mean wrapper class can't be in header file.

Comment: Either put a static assert with a user-friendly message, or, define the class template's member functions in an implementation file, and implicitly instantiate only for the preferred subset of types

Comment: I've also tried static_assert but I got an error that typeid(Type) == typeid(SDL_Window) isn't a constant expression

Comment: You'd need `std::is_same<Type, SDL_Window>::value`, or use some template machinery like boost mpl list or your custom implementation

Comment: Ok so static_assert filled with is_same statements works. Still is there a way to hide Wrapper completely, while only seeing defined aliases?

Comment: You need at least the declaration to be in a header file, and explicitly instantiate the class tempalte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Best scenario I would like to achieve would be to make Wrapper class not visible outside the usage of aliases I create.

This is possible using `private` and a wrapper class

```
class WrapperAccessor {
    template < typename Type >
    class Wrapper {
    public:
       Wrapper(Type* resource) : ptr(resource) {}
       ~Wrapper() { free(ptr); }

    private:
       Type* ptr;
    };

public:
    using Window = Wrapper<SDL_Window>;
    using Renderer = Wrapper<SDL_Renderer>;
};

using Window = WrapperAccessor::Window;
using Renderer = WrapperAccessor::Renderer;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), which will enable only certain types for your classes/functions?

Take a look at [type_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) in C++11 and 14. You can do all kinds of static checks (checks at compile-time). For example, to check if the type is what you're expecting, you can use:

```
std::is_same<T,int>::value
```

And this will return true *at compile time* if `T` is `int`.

Comment: I would probably go with something similar to check for the allowed types.

Comment: So I've tried this, specified all the types it should allow and then created an Wrapper<int>. It compiled and runs even though int specialization shouldn't be allowed at all, also no idea what happened in it's destructor because free(int) overload doesn't exist.

Comment: @MarošBeťko If you don't want it to compile, then use `static_if`, instead of `if`. Here's how you implement it in C++11: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617677/implementing-a-compile-time-static-if-logic-for-different-string-types-in-a-co

Comment: @MarošBeťko Also if you use `std::enable_if`, you can prevent compiling with types you don't want. But `enable_if` has some steep learning curve and you have to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help

```
template <typename T, bool Allowed>
class WrapperBase;


template <typename T>
class WrapperBase<T, true>
{
};

template <typename T>
class WrapperBase<T, false>;

template < typename Type >
class WrapperBaseHelper : public WrapperBase<T, boost::is_base_of<SDL_Window, T>::value | boost::is_base_of<SDL_Renderer>::value ...e.t.c >
{
...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, I would use `std::unique_ptr`, something like:

```
template <typename T, T value> struct Call; // c++17 should allow Call<auto F>

template <typename T, void (*f)(T*)>
struct Call<void (*)(T*), f>
{
    void operator ()(T* p) const { f(p); }
};

#define AUTO(F) decltype(F), F // not needed in C++17

using Window = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, Call<AUTO(&SDL_DestroyWindow)>>;
using Renderer = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Renderer, Call<AUTO(&SDL_DestroyRenderer)>>;
```

That handles deleted copy and correct move semantic contrary to your snippet.