# Checking Datatypes of Template Function

Tags: c++, typechecking, template-function

I'm trying to make a function based on input Template. It reads a file.

```
template<class size> void config::readConfig(char * setting, char * subsetting, size & status) {
    char temp[255];
    if (!GetPrivateProfileStringA(setting, subsetting, nullptr, temp, 255, cfg)) {
        error = true;
    }
    if (std::is_same<size, char [4]>::value) {
        sprintf_s(status, "%s", temp);
    } else { status = atof(temp); }
}
```

I'm basically just checking if the desired input is a char. If it is, then we'll copy the char read over, but if not, we'll copy the bool/int/float/double. Maybe I'm just using std::is_same incorrectly.

My code won't compile because it doesn't look like it recognizes the check and seems like it always returns true.

Comment: Try to steer towards using `std::string` whenever you can. Bare, mutable character buffers are nothing but trouble.

Comment: Instead of using a template function, why not offer an implementation for `float` and one for `int`?

Comment: I'm trying to challenge myself to minimize the amount of code as much as possible. Why double the amount of code when I can put one check? I'd use std::string but I end up at the same fault in the is_same check

Comment: There's challenging yourself and there's missing the point of function overloading. Template functions aren't intended for this kind of use case. If the function you call to convert varies depending on the type you need to overload. Define functions that can handle the inputs you're expecting, don't have a catch-all that might catch garbage.

Comment: But you're also forgetting the cases where people specify `status` as something completely crazy like, say, a `std::vector<std::map<int, void*>>`.

Comment: @tadman they're used absolutely the same, just copied differently.

Comment: @TravisGockel I'm the one using them in my code, and I only read bool, int, float, double, and string/char from the ini file. No one will ever see my code :P

Comment: Templates are compile-time while you are trying to perform runtime check. Just create a function overload (template specialization).

Comment: @tempman You're making code that's overly ornate here, it's not a template problem. It's not even clear why you can't have a simple return type here that the caller can cast/convert/mangle as necessary.

Comment: @tadman I have multiple variables I'm reading from a config file, and this is the shortest way to read it. Setting a return would require me to retype hundreds of lines of code from just calling a function to setting some value to the return of that function

Comment: @tempman: Your code still doesn't cover those cases -- why do you want to use `atof` to parse a `bool`, `int`, `string`, `char*` of arbitrary length, etc? Why _only_ match mutable `char[]` of length `4`?

Comment: @tempman Arguably this code is a prime candidate for refactoring for a multitude of reasons. Why fossilize a bad design by doubling down on it? Fix it using function overloading. Refactor it later so that's not necessary. A return value is always going to be more understandable than passing in a mutable argument.

Comment: At runtime, they'll automatically convert and any data I lose won't matter as round errors don't matter to the code. Char 4 is just to read the config version to make sure it's all formatted correctly to help specify reasons for failure when reading config. The version is currently 1.0 @TravisGockel

Comment: @tadman then I'd need to check what I'm reading as opposed to what I want to read. It'd definitely make more sense, but my objective is to not have to rewrite every single variable being assigned

Comment: @AndreyNasonov Sounds like the correct answer as to why it won't compile - so regardless I'll just have to make a specialization. Please post it as a response so I can mark it as correct :)

Comment: @tadman you can't overload functions based on return value. The OP's example uses an output parameter  and you can overload on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't compile because an `if` statement is a runtime construct. Consider this code:

```
int foo(bool b)
{
    if (b)
    {
        // attempt to call a function that does not exist
        function_that_does_not_exist();
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

You can talk to me all day about how `b` is *always* `false`, but the compiler still requires the code in the `true` case of the `if` block to compile. What's happening in your example for something like an `int` is this:

```
template<>
void config::readConfig(char* setting, char* subsetting, int& status) {
    char temp[255];
    if (!GetPrivateProfileStringA(setting, subsetting, nullptr, temp, 255, cfg)) {
        error = true;
    }

    // if (std::is_same<size, char [4]>::value) {
    if (false) {
        sprintf_s(status, "%s", temp);
    } else { status = atof(temp); }
}
```

The compiler does not know how to make `sprintf_s` compile when `status` is an `int`.

The solution is to use overloading:

```
template<class size>
void config::readConfig(char * setting, char * subsetting, size & status) {
    char temp[255];
    if (!GetPrivateProfileStringA(setting, subsetting, nullptr, temp, 255, cfg)) {
        error = true;
    }

    status = atof(temp);
}

template<size_t N>
void config::readConfig(char* setting, char* subsetting, char (&status)[N]) {
    char temp[255];
    if (!GetPrivateProfileStringA(setting, subsetting, nullptr, temp, 255, cfg)) {
        error = true;
    }

    sprintf_s(status, "%s", temp);
}
```

---

The thing you're looking for is usually referred to as `static_if` (similar to the D conditional compilation construct of a ["Static If Condition"](https://dlang.org/spec/version.html#staticif)). There is no support in C++17 and it isn't planned for C++2a (yet), but you can emulate it easily with the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617677/).

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename F>
auto static_if(std::true_type, T t, F f) { return t; }

template <typename T, typename F>
auto static_if(std::false_type, T t, F f) { return f; }

template <bool B, typename T, typename F>
auto static_if(T t, F f) { return static_if(std::integral_constant<bool, B>{}, t, f); }

template <class size>
void config::readConfig(char* setting, char* subsetting, size& status)
{
    char temp[255];
    if (!GetPrivateProfileStringA(setting, subsetting, nullptr, temp, 255, cfg))
    {
        error = true;
    }

    static_if<std::is_same<size, char [4]>::value>
    (
        [&] (auto& status) { sprintf_s(status, "%s", temp); },
        [&] (auto& status) { status = atof(temp); }
    )(status);
}
```