# Difference between "if constexpr()" Vs "if()"

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr

What is the difference between `if constexpr()` and `if()`?

Where and When can I use both of them?

Comment: A starting point: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Comment: @Rakete1111 constexpr if() and if constexpr() are same?

Comment: @rsp No, P0292R1 is newer than P0128R1. There is also a note that P0292R1 revises P0128R1, so `if constexpr` is the new syntax, not `constexpr if`, which isn't valid.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The only difference is that `if constexpr` is evaluated at compile time, whereas `if` is not. This means that branches can be rejected at compile time, and thus will never get compiled.

---

Imagine you have a function, `length`, that returns the length of a number, or the length of a type that has a `.length()` function. You can't do it in one function, the compiler will complain:

```
template<typename T>
auto length(const T& value) noexcept {
    if (std::is_integral<T>::value) { // is number
        return value;
       }
    else{
        return value.length();
    }
}

int main() noexcept {
    int a = 5;
    std::string b = "foo";

    std::cout << length(a) << ' ' << length(b) << '\n'; // doesn't compile
}
```

Error message:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'auto length(const T&) [with T = int]':
main.cpp:16:26:   required from here
main.cpp:9:16: error: request for member 'length' in 'val', which is of non-class type 'const int'
     return val.length();
            ~~~~^~~~~~
```

That's because when the compiler instantiates `length`, the function will look like this:

```
auto length(const int& value) noexcept {
    if (std::is_integral<int>::value) { // is number
        return value;
    else
        return value.length();
}
```

`value` is an `int`, and as such doesn't have a `length` member function, and so the compiler complains. The compiler can't see that statement will never be reached for an `int`, but it doesn't matter, as the compiler can't guarantee that.

Now you can either specialize `length`, but for a lot of types (like in this case - every number and class with a `length` member function), this results in a lot of duplicated code. SFINAE is also a solution, but it requires multiple function definitions, which makes the code a lot longer than it needs to be compared to the below.

Using `if constexpr` instead of `if` means that the branch (`std::is_integral<T>::value`) will get evaluated at compile time, and if it is `true` then every other branch (`else if` and `else`) gets discarded. If it is `false`, the next branch is checked (here `else`), and if it is `true`, discard every other branch, and so on...

```
template<typename T>
auto length(const T& value) noexcept {
    if constexpr (std::integral<T>::value) { // is number
        return value;
    else
        return value.length();
}
```

Now, when the compiler will instantiate `length`, it will look like this:

```
int length(const int& value) noexcept {
    //if constexpr (std::is_integral<int>::value) { this branch is taken
        return value;
    //else                           discarded
    //    return value.length();     discarded
}

std::size_t length(const std::string& value) noexcept {
    //if constexpr (std::is_integral<int>::value) { discarded
    //    return value;                   discarded
    //else                           this branch is taken
        return value.length();
}
```

And so those 2 overloads are valid, and the code will compile successfully.

Comment: Note that without `if constexpr` you can have length call a template struct and (partially) specialise that in oder to avoid code duplication. The main benefit of `if constexpr` is thus IMO the more "natural" appearance to the programmer.

Comment: ... never mind my previous comment, I see you did indeed include the fact I noted on (_"... and if it is `true` then every other branch (`else if` and `else`) gets discarded."_).

Comment: ```if (std::integral<T>::value) { // is number``` at the beginning should be ```std::is_integral<T>::value``` instead

Answer (score 79):

The ordinary `if` statement:

- Has its condition evaluated every time control reaches it, if ever
- Determines which of the two substatements to execute, skipping the other
- Requires both substatements to be well-formed regardless of which one is actually selected at runtime

The `if constexpr` statement:

- Has its condition evaluated at compile time once all necessary template arguments have been supplied
- Determines which of the two substatements to compile, discarding the other
- Does not require the discarded substatement to be well-formed

Comment: The arguments don't necessarily have to be *template* arguments though, no? Also, why only two substatements? Can't there be more?

Comment: @Rakete1111 A valid constant expression can only depend on the values of variables that were previously initialized. So once the compiler sees an `if constexpr` statement, it should already have enough information to evaluate the condition. The only exception is when the statement appears in a template, in which case there may not be enough information until the template arguments are specified. A constant expression can't depend on ordinary function arguments, since their values are not known at compile time.

Comment: @Rakete1111 An if statement always has either one or two substatements. If you have `if ... else if ... else ...` then you really have two if statements, one nested within the other, each of which has two substatements.

Comment: "Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. if constexpr is not a substitute for the #if preprocessing directive". Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Comment: This is a little of-topic and heretic, but, why not just `if`? Compiler can decide if it is a `if constexpr` or just `if`. So, this thing does not affect programmers BUT specification must change: if an `if` condition evaluated compile time, only `if` or `else` code compiled. But this is transparent for programmer. Just curious.

Comment: Is it correct to use the term "compile" rather than "instantiate". See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63469333/11205473)

Comment: @Chameleon https://stackoverflow.com/a/40972822/