# Compile Error in template on non-called cast function

Tags: c++, templates, if-statement, inheritance, casting

I'm working with another persons code that uses a function
 `doSomething` that depends on two templates: `stage` and `T`.
I know that they can just take the states (`Micro`, 
`DerivedOne`) or (`Macro`, `DerivedTwo`)

In `doSomething` I  now need to cast `DerivedTwo` to `BaseTwo` and `DerivedOne` to `BaseOne`. As seen in the code the conversions are only 
made when the stage is right, i.e.they are always o.k.
Still I get compile errors because it is not possible to cast `DerivedOne`
to `BaseTwo` even though this cast is never made.

Question:
How can I get this code to compile without changing the general structure of the involved classes and templates? (This would break to many other parts of the code).
Preferably I only want to change `doSomething`.

The cast occurs b.c. I need to call an overloaded function that can either
take `BaseOne` or `BaseTwo`. Hence, to pass `DerivedTwo` I need to explicitly cast it.

aTest.h

```
enum  Stage {
    Micro,
    Macro
};

class BaseOne
{
 int a;
};

class BaseTwo
{
int b;
};


class DerivedOne : public  BaseOne
{
 int c;
};

class DerivedTwo: public  BaseTwo, public  BaseOne
{
int d;
};

template  <Stage stage>
class Doer{
    template <class T>
    void doSomething( T t);

};
```

aTest.cpp

```
#include "aTest.h"

template< Stage stage >
template < class T >
void Doer<stage>::doSomething(T t) {


 //depending on stage we need to cast t to BaseOne or BaseTwo
 if( stage == Micro )
 {
  overloadedFunction( (BaseOne) t );
 }
 if( stage == Macro )
 {
  overloadedFunction( (BaseTwo) t );
 }



}


template  class Doer<Micro>;
template class Doer<Macro>;


template void Doer<Micro>::doSomething(DerivedOne t);
template void Doer<Macro>::doSomething(DerivedTwo t);
```

Comment: even though the cast is never made? According to this reasoning also `if (1==0) { syntax error; }` should compile. The code containing the cast is instantiated, so it has to be valid. I am not fluent on c++11 and beyond template stuff, but maybe a constexpr if may help

Comment: `if constexpr (..)` in C++17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
if constexpr (stage == Macro)
     overloadedFunction( (BaseTwo) t );
```

Now why will this come in handy?

Because now that the if-statement contains `constexpr`, it will evaluate its condition at *compile time*, and will compile its body, only if the condition evaluates to true. That means that the body might be ill-formed, and yet the code to be able to compile. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434491/difference-between-if-constexpr-vs-if).