# Only add templated argument to an array if it's of a specific type

Tags: c++

I have a problem which I can't get my head wrapped around. I have two type definitions for callbacks (used by lambdas later on):

```
typedef std::function<void(Payload1 Payload)> Callback1;
typedef std::function<void(Payload2 Payload)> Callback2;
```

Where as Payload1 and Payload2 are different structs containing event payload data. Then I got two arrays (as I am using, those are TArrays, but that doesn't matter), which contain the callbacks:

```
TArray<Callback1> Callback1Array;
TArray<Callback2> Callback2Array;
```

And a templated function which should add the callback into the array where it fits in:

```
template<typename CallbackType>
void SubscribeToEvent(CallbackType Callback)
{
    // If CallbackType is Callback1
    Callback1Array.Add(Callback);

    // Else If CallbackType is Callback2
    Callback2Array.Add(Callback);
}
```

I am not sure how I can express the statements I wrote in the comments. It will obviously fail if it tries to add a Callback2 type into the Callback1 array, so I somehow need to check the type, and only add it into the right array, and don't even try to add it in the others. Is this possible?

Thank you :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @PasserBy Changed the thread to a better one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question directly, you *could* write what you commented

```
template<typename CallbackType>
void SubscribeToEvent(CallbackType Callback)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<CallbackType, Callback1>)
        Callback1Array.Add(Callback);

    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<CallbackType, Callback2>)
        Callback2Array.Add(Callback);
}
```

But that looks like gross misuse of [`if constexpr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434491/difference-between-if-constexpr-vs-if)

This is typically where you overload your `SubscribeToEvent` instead of using templates.

```
void SubscribeToEvent(Callback1 Callback)
{
    Callback1Array.Add(Callback);
}

void SubscribeToEvent(Callback2 Callback)
{
    Callback2Array.Add(Callback);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, allthough this involves more writing work, it makes my framework more readable :)

Answer (score 1):

With `std::tuple` you may do something like:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class Foo
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    using Callback = std::function<void(T)>;

    template <typename T>
    using EventArray = TArray<Callback<T>>;


    template <typename T>
    void SubscribeEvent(Callback<T> callback)
    {
        GetCallbackArray<T>().Add(callback);
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    EventArray<T>& GetCallbackArray() { return std::get<EventArray<T>>(eventCallbacks); }

private:
    std::tuple<EventArray<Ts>...> eventCallbacks;
};

using MyClass = Foo<FRpcEventPayload_Ready /*, ...*/>;
```