# Check Equality of Types

Tags: c++, templates

I have a struct and template class, within which there is a function that should check if T is equal to the struct and if so, do something.

The struct:

```
struct mystruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;    
};
```

the template class:

```
template <typename T>
class myclass
{
    public:
    void myfunc()
    {
        // this condition is ignored..
        if(std::is_same<T,mystruct>::value==0)
        {
             cout << "T is not mystruct type" << '\n';

        }
        else
        {
            T ms;
            ms.x = 5;
            ms.y = 4;
            ms.z = 3;
        }
    }
};
```

in main function, if T == mystruct everything goes through fine:

```
int main()
{
    // no issues
   myclass<mystruct> x;
   x.myfunc();
}
```

but if T != mystruct:

```
int main()
{
    //tries to unsuccessfuly convert int to mystruct
   myclass<int> x;
   x.myfunc();
}
```

execution fails with the below error:

```
error: request for member 'x' in 'ms', which is of non-class type 'int'
             ms.x = 5;
```

does anyone have an idea why the if-else statement not working as expected?
Thanks!

Comment: Which version of C++ are you targetting? If C++17 is targeted, you can use a `if constexpr`. Else you must use SFINAE

Comment: Possible duplicate [Difference between if constexpr vs if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434491/difference-between-if-constexpr-vs-if)

Comment: Thank you @Antoine Morrier! I will give `if constexpr` a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the `if` condition evaluates to `false`, for a particular template instantiation, the entire template still must consist of valid C++ code.

If the template's parameter is `int`, for example, then the `else` part of the `if` statement becomes equivalent to:

```
    else
    {
        int ms;
        ms.x = 5;
        ms.y = 4;
        ms.z = 3;
    }
```

It should be obvious why this won't compile. Because the entire template becomes, equivalent to:

```
    if (true)
    {
        cout << "T is not mystruct type" << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        int ms;
        ms.x = 5;
        ms.y = 4;
        ms.z = 3;
    }
```

Even though `else` never gets executed, it stlil must be valid C++ code. Templates are no different.

C++17 introduced [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) which requires that the evaluated `if` expression is constant, and only the appropriate part of the `if` statement ends up being compiled, with the rest being effectively discarded. So, with C++17, you should be able to change the `if` statement to `if constexpr`, and get the expected results.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sam Varshavchik. I was going nuts over this one..I will try the `if constexpr` and see how it goes. much appreciated!