# c++ : Defferentiate templates in an if statement

Tags: c++, templates, vector, struct

I seem to have the following problem. I have a `class BSK` (Binary Knapsack) which contains a `struct Item` in which an `identifier` can be `std::string` or `int`. Then I have a `vector<Items> itemlist_`  and I need to insert a new Item in the beginning. I am trying to do something like this and it works for `int` but does not work for `string`. Thank you!

```
template <class T>
class BKS final
{
public:
    struct Item
    {
        T identifier;
        int weight;
        int benefit;
    };
     // some methods ...
}
```

I am trying to do something like this and it works for `int` but does not work for `string`. Thank you!

```
if(std::is_same<T, int>::value){
    Item toInsert = {0,0,0};
    itemlist_.insert(itemlist_.begin(), toInsert);
else{
    Item toInsert = {"aa", 0, 0};
    itemlist_.insert(itemlist_.begin(), toInsert);
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the correct (only one of) part of if at compile time. Normal `if` statement can not do that. Read more:

[Difference between "if constexpr()" Vs "if()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434491/difference-between-if-constexpr-vs-if)

You need [`if-constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

Suggestion: In addition, you do not need extra `toInsert`, pass the temporary, to the `itemlist_`.

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value)
{
    itemlist_.insert(itemlist_.begin(), {0,0,0});
} 
else if constexpr(std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
{
    itemlist_.insert(itemlist_.begin(), {"aa", 0, 0});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that both the if part and else part have to be well-formed at compile-time. The statement `Item toInsert = {"aa", 0, 0};` is ill-formed when `T` is `int`.

You can use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17).

> If the value is true, then *statement-false* is discarded (if present), otherwise, *statement-true* is discarded.

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
    Item toInsert = {0,0,0};
    itemlist_.insert(itemlist_.begin(), toInsert);
} else {
    Item toInsert = {"aa", 0, 0};
    itemlist_.insert(itemlist_.begin(), toInsert);
}
```

Comment: No, they aren't both evaluated. They have to both be well-formed.

Comment: Thak you, this seems to be fixing the problem