# Why does the false branch of "if constexpr" get compiled?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr

Why is this code giving error while compiling? My knowledge (and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434491/difference-between-if-constexpr-vs-if)) of "**`if constexpr`**" says the `else` block shouldn't get compiled.

```
if constexpr (true) {
    int a = 10;
} else {
    int b = 10
}
```

The error is:

```
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
```

Compiler used: **g++ version 7.5.0**
While compiling I used **`-std=c++17`** flag.

**P.S.** The missing ';' is intentional, just to check whether `else` is being compiled or not.

Comment: Maybe you should make it explicit that the missing ```;``` is purposeful; at least that seems to be your intention to me (to test if the ```else``` block is being compiled I presume).

Comment: There is a world of difference between "doesn't get compiled" (or instantiated) and "doesn't parse".

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question, and the intent of the code snippet is clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 2 separate, but related issues here.

Firstly, `if constexpr` will only conditionally compile a branch within a template. Outside of a template, all branches will be compiled and must be well formed.

Secondly, even in a template, the discarded branch of an `if constexpr` can't be ill-formed for all possible instantiations. This is not the case in your code, since:

```
int b = 10
```

is always ill-formed (due to the missing `;`).

So the compiler is correct in giving a compile error. Technically, if the discarded branch is ill-formed for all instantiations, then the compiler is not *required* to give a compiler error, but the code is still wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can you explain a bit more on "within a template"?

Comment: Also, the second case is NDR.

Comment: @KishanShukla `if constexpr` behave a bit like a template. The false branch is still compiled, but not always instantiated. If there is no dependent types, then all branched are checked for validity. This is not like the preprocessor.

Comment: @KishanShukla See the [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if). There is an example where it shows that the `if constexpr` needs to be dependent on `T` inside a `template<typename T>` for one of the branches to be discarded.

Comment: @T.C.: Is it really?  It doesn’t even *parse*, so I’m not sure we reach the level of analysis that “checks” for a possible instantiation.

Comment: @DavisHerring Last time I checked we still allow token soup implementations.

Comment: @T.C.: Lacking a definition for instantiation, I can’t say whether the bad syntax should be part of it.  The grammar certainly “sees” into everything even if it’s a known implementation technique to match only `{…}` in that circumstance.

Comment: @DavisHerring [temp.res]/8 has an equally non-parsing example. /shrug

Comment: Yeah, it says `void g(T t) { +; }` *may* be diagnosed, so it doesn't seem to be required, even if parsing would fail.

Comment: The missing semi colon likely causes compilation to fail as early as during the [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) stage or right after it. At that point the expression in the `if` clause didn't have a chance to be run.