# Why code under if constexpr evaluates even if the condition is false?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

What is the specific reason C++ continues to evaluate code inside `if constexpr` block even when the condition is false?

Is it because the compiler need to have "evaluable" code in order to be able to find the respective if code block's closing brace or just in order to make sure (what for?) that the code in block is compilable in both cases (false/true)?

Is there another reason language does so?

Because of the such behaviour in the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/c9f57hrzd) below I have to make trick with WorkerStub. Otherwize, I could just use empty template.

```
constexpr bool param = false;

struct WorkerStub {
    void do_work() {}
};

struct RealWorker {
    void do_work() {
        // Some real hard work
    }
};

template<bool cond>
struct conditional_worker {
    WorkerStub worker;  // This could have been removed in case if-constexpr didn't evaluate code in its block when the condition is false
};

template<>
struct conditional_worker<true>
{
    RealWorker worker;
};

class Client : public conditional_worker<param> {
    void foo() {
        if constexpr (param) {
            worker.do_work();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
}
```

Of course, this could easily done with `#define`, but I want to have a solution without macros and without an excessive (although light-weight and in most cases candidate to optimize-out) object.

Not to be confused with the [if constexpr - why is discarded statement fully checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393908/if-constexpr-why-is-discarded-statement-fully-checked) and [Why does the false branch of "if constexpr" get compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63469333/why-does-the-false-branch-of-if-constexpr-get-compiled) which answers how `if constexpr` works stating "this is the way how it works". My question is **why** does it work in this way. Why such a decision was made in language.

Comment: `if constexpr` only discards code in templates. Neither `Client` nor `foo` is a template, so this `if constexpr` doesn't do anything special (except that condition must still be compile time constant).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, should this template somehow depend on `if constexpr` condition or this could be just any template? If I wrap `Client` to template which has nothing to do with `param`, would this work?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: No, both the condition of `if constexpr` must depend on the template parameter, and the error you want to hide must depend on it too. http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1

Comment: @Damir No, `if constexpr` condition has to depend on the template type. It's hard to propose a solution, since nothing in your code requires templates at the moment. What I suppose should be there is `Client` is templated on `bool param` or inherit from some template argument `T` and in `if constexpr` you check if it really has `worker` member.

Comment: @kiner_shah, MSVC latest, but why?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thank you, I get it. Any clues on why such a decision is made in language?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, any way to rework the [code above](https://godbolt.org/z/c9f57hrzd) to template avoiding the WorkerStub?

Comment: I've reopened question after edit, although from my experience questions "why did standard decide to do things like this?" are not very welcome here, since they tend to devolve into opinions. There may be objective answer, particularly if the paper prosing feature has an explanation, but we still may not know what was discussed in CWG about that.

Comment: when `if constexpr (param) { worker.do_work(); }` is not in a template then nothing can make the code take the branch and nothing can make `worker.do_work()` be "ok". What you ask for is the language letting you write wrong code. What would that be good for?

Comment: Because it's usually a good thing if the compiler catches errors in templates early, before they are instantiated (if the error doesn't depend on the template parameters). And if we limit the magic powers of `if constexpr` to errors that depend on template parameters, it's only natural that it does nothing outside of templates (would be weird for it to prevent all errors outside of templates, and only some inside).

Comment: Use a macro and `#if` for your `bool param`.

Comment: `constexpr bool param = false;` means "this variable cannot possibly change its value". If you want a `Client` that has different implementation depending on  a `param` you can make `Client` a template with `param` template argument

Comment: `if constexpr` for conditional compilation was controversial when it was originally proposed (as `static if`). Some arguments can be seen here: https://wg21.link/n3613 .

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, thank you. Let's aim to have some objective technical-oriented answer, since it have a good chance to be. Like "in case you do so, you will have such and such consequences or you will have to violate this". (Somebody again closed the question based on the "how it works?" question instead of "why such a decision was made").

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, my idea is to use `if constexpr` like a `#ifdef` block which will allow me to configure my application based on compile-time parameters. For example, in my case `RealWorker` is some debugging/tracing tool used for gather statistics on class usage. I want to conditionally exclude it from build, since it is expensive in real-time. Of course, I can do this with `#ifdef`, but preprocessor directives not natural to the code and looks no so good. What is wrong with my intentions/approach here?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, from this perspective, how this solution is different from `#ifdef` approach which is used widely in `std` and other libraries? Well, we just push a programmer to use `#ifdef` instead of `if constexpr` (in case my approach is not applicable for some reason) and they will have absolutely the same without any control from compiler side. I mean safe for my trick, what approach for this task you would suggest to developer to benefit from this `if constexpr` behaviour?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, on the `Use a macro and #if for your bool param`, isn't that what I covered with my "Of course, this could easily done with #define, but I want to have a solution without macros and without an excessive (although light-weight and in most cases candidate to optimize-out) object." below the code? Should I reword to make more explicit? Of course, I would like to avoid preprocessor as much as possible.

Comment: "my idea is to use if constexpr like a #ifdef block which will allow me to configure my application based on compile-time parameters." but you can do that already. Make `Client` a template parametrized on `param` and it will work

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, On the `If you want a Client that has different implementation depending on a param you can make Client a template with param template argument`. Can you please pinpoint the idea, I tried [this](https://godbolt.org/z/rq6WTnasc), but most likely I miss something.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/G3rTK6rGW

Comment: you miss that `worker` needs `this->`, its a dependant name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, thank you for the hint, I really met this for first time somehow. So, applying your answer and defaulting the template parameter to `param` I get [what I wanted initially](https://godbolt.org/z/cYMq53EEc). This helps, thank you. Anyway, the initial question gets back to the table, why such a decision was made that it works in template only? If there is no difference in code and code generation and I got everything for free, why it works with templates only? So far, I mostly focused on document link provided by *Artyer* above.

Comment: my counter question still holds: Why do you think you need it when you can use it inside templates? Inside a template either of the two branches is taken. Outside of a template there is no mechanism that would the code sometimes take one branch and sometimes another branch, so what you would get is a way to write wrong code that the compiler never checks. Thats not something desirable.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I was (mistakenly, as I see now) sure that `if constexpr` is exactly the such mechanism for any place of code. How could I have known the opposite? When I look at the [en.cppreference.com]( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) I don’t see at the beginning any references to template nature of `if constexpr` and (to be continued...)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, (...continue) only in the examples and in the middle I see an alone line “*Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. if constexpr is not a substitute for the #if preprocessing directive*”, but this is “in the middle of nowhere” and in no means answer the question “why?”. Again, I understand how it works, I don’t understand why it doesn’t work in a way [Static If](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3613.pdf) could have worked.