# affect of constexpr on Parameter pack

Tags: c++, constexpr, parameter-pack

Why is this code invalid without `constexpr`:

```
template<typename ...Tpack>
auto CalculateSum(Tpack ...pack)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Tpack) > 0)
    return (pack + ...);
    else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << CalculateSum(2, 3, 4, 5, 7.5, 6) << '\n';
}
```

whereas if there are only `int` in the arguments, it gets valid.

Compiler says: 'auto' in return type deduced as 'int' here but deduced as 'double' in earlier return statement

But how does `constexpr` resolves?

Comment: The compiler error ought to explain it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to mix types like that (`int` with `double`)?

Comment: @AnmolMishra regarding your suggested edit, while `constexpr` is a part of C++11, a fold expression and if constexpr are both C++17 features, so that tag is incorrect.  The current C++ tag means C++20, which is okay for this Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you need the `if constexpr` instead of a plain `if` is that you are trying to return two different types, which is not allowed with automatic return type deduction.

With `return (pack + ...);` the return type is going to be `double` because one of your parameters is a `double`.  On the other hand, `return 0;` is going to return an `int`.  Since those type do not match, you get an error.  You need to `if constexpr` to make either `return (pack + ...);` or `return 0;` be the only line of code that actually gets compiled, which leaves you with just a single type that the function could return.

If you switch to using a trailing return type, you can get rid of the `if constexpr` and use a plain `if` like

```
template<typename ...Tpack>
auto CalculateSum(Tpack ...pack) -> decltype((pack + ...))
{
    if (sizeof...(Tpack) > 0)
        return (pack + ...);
    else
        return {};
}
```

But that isn't [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#:%7E:text=%22Don%27t%20repeat%20yourself%22,data%20normalization%20to%20avoid%20redundancy.) and is more typing, so I prefer the `if constexpr` version.

Comment: I will just expand your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43434771/14934019