# Suppress compiler error for a single line MSVC19 C++20

Tags: c++, visual-c++, error-handling, c++20

I want to check if a `shared_ptr` is uninitialized, i.e. if it is a `nullptr` or if it has a default value (as would be the case if created by using `std::make_shared`). For this purpose I wrote a code to check if the shared pointer is having a default constructed value of a class/struct. To achieve this, I also need to know if a class/struct defines the `operator==` and to figure that out I have `has_equate`. The code to check if a shared pointer is uninitialized is:

```
template<class L, class R = L>
concept has_equate = requires(const L & lhs, const R & rhs)
{
    { lhs == rhs } -> std::same_as<bool>;
};

template <typename T>
bool isSharedPtrUninitialized(const std::shared_ptr<T>& shared)
{
    if(shared) {
        if(has_equate<T>) {
            T tmp;
            if(*shared == tmp)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If I don't define `operator==` for my class/struct the above line of code gives the following error:

> Error C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Since I am checking if the `operator==` exists or not for the class/struct by using `has_equate` before proceeding to check if the given shared pointer has a default constructed value, I would like to suppress this error for this particular line of code.

What I have tried so far:

```
template <typename T>
bool isSharedPtrUninitialized(const std::shared_ptr<T>& shared)
{
    if(shared) {
        if(has_equate<T>) {
            T tmp;
            #pragma warning(suppress: 2678)
            if(*shared == tmp)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 2678)
template <typename T>
bool isSharedPtrUninitialized(const std::shared_ptr<T>& shared)
{
    if(shared) {
        if(has_equate<T>) {
            T tmp;
            if(*shared == tmp)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
#pragma warning(pop)
```

None of it is working (I assume it is because C2678 is an error and not a warning). Is there a way I could suppress this error for just `if(*shared == tmp)` line of code or just for the `isSharedPtrUninitialized` function as I do not want to do this for the entire thing.

Comment: If the compiler thinks it’s an error there’s nothing you can do about it than write it in a way that the compiler won’t think it’s an error. You can’t disable errors because the compiler doesn’t know what to do with the code. It can’t just skip that line from compiling.

Comment: `if constexpr` is your friend.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks! it solved the problem for me :)

Comment: The default initialization scares me; maybe you want `*shared == T()`?

Comment: @DavisHerring `*shared == T()` would be shorter in code but won't it be the same in terms of usage? Are there any shortcomings that I am missing here?

Comment: @Chaitanya: It’s value-initialization, which is less likely to produce undefined behavior in the comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo) for providing the solution. The working function is:

```
template <typename T>
bool isSharedPtrUninitialized(const std::shared_ptr<T>& shared)
{
    if(shared) {
        if constexpr (has_equate<T>) {
            T tmp;
            if(*shared == tmp)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Using `if constexpr` instead of `if` solved the problem for me. If curious about the difference between these two then have a look at the post [Difference between "if constexpr()" Vs "if()"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43434491/6095822) on SO.