# How can I combine a template function with a free function?

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++20, function-templates

I am not sure, if it's possible, but take this snippet of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct car {
    float speed;
};

struct bike {
    float speed;
};

void drive(float* speed)
{
    printf("driving at speed %f\n", *speed);
}

template<typename T>
void drive(T driveable)
{
    drive(&driveable->speed);
}

int main() {
    struct car car = { .speed = 10.f };
    struct bike bike = { .speed = 20.f };
    drive(&car);
    drive(&bike);
}
```

The idea is that any object that has a member field of type `float` and that is named `speed` can be used transparently with the function `drive`. Thanks to the template-overload function `drive`, which passes the member of the template type to the actual `drive` free-function.

Is it possible, to combine the template - function with the free-function in a single one? Something along the lines:

```
template<typename T>
void drive(T driveable)
void drive(float *speed = &driveable->speed)
{
    printf("driving at speed %f\n", *speed);
}
```

Additionally, would there be another, more elegant way to do what I want?

Comment: There is no need to combine them. No need for micro-optimizations.

Comment: Why not just write `printf("driving at speed %f\n", driveable->speed)`?

Comment: @JasonLiam Well, the goal isn't to achieve micro-optimizations, but rather just to make the API more concise.

Comment: @Nelfeal Because driveable may contain other fields which I don't want my function to have access to, unless explicitly stated.

Comment: @aganm But your function template does have access to those other fields. And the functions in both answers (as of yet) also do. It sounds like you want an interface, as in an object-oriented abstract class `drivable` that `car` and `bike` inherit from. AFAIK that's the only way to achieve exactly what you want, apart from just calling `drive` with the speed directly. Personally, I would just *not access* those other fields, because that's my function and my types and I do what I want with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to combine the templated function with the non-templated function in a single one?

Yes, it is possible. On the other hand, having two overloads in your case is more readable.

If you insist on doing so, using [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) (since [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)) and compile time branching using [`if constexpr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434491/difference-between-if-constexpr-vs-if) (since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)) you may do:

```
#include <concepts> // std::floating_point

// concept for checking whether T has "speed" member, which is floating point!
template<typename T>
concept has_float_member = requires (T t) {  // nested requirements
    requires std::floating_point<decltype(t.speed)>;
};

void drive(auto const& driveable)
{
    if constexpr (has_float_member<decltype(driveable)>)
        drive(driveable.speed);
    else // optional: if constexpr (std::floating_point<std::decay_t<decltype(driveable)>>)
        std::printf("Driving at speed: %f\n", driveable);
}
```

[See a demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vsozdYYb1)

Now you can call the same function for `car`, `bike`, and `float`s as follows.

```
drive(car);  // pass car and bike like
drive(bike);
drive(2.f);
```

If you required to pass the references to the instances, adjust the function accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

There is no syntax similar to the one you are proposing. Having two seperate overloads as two seperate overloads is "elegant" enough. Your code is fine as is.

Though, if you want, there is a way to have a single function template that can cover both cases:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

struct car {
    float speed;
};

struct bike {
    float speed;
};

template<typename T>
void drive(const T& t)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<float,T>) {
        printf("driving at speed %f\n",t);
    } else {    
        drive(t.speed);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct car car = { .speed = 10.f };
    struct bike bike = { .speed = 20.f };
    drive(car);
    drive(bike);
    drive(0.5f);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7bTE1Kb6j)

Whether this or your code is more elegant is largely a matter of opinions.

PS: There is quite a bit of pointless use of pointers in your code. I removed that. Also in C++ you should use the C++ header called `cstdio` rather than the C header `stdio.h`.

Comment: I don't believe this will compile when drive is passed a variable of type float... Or int. Or double. Or any other type which does not have speed member.

Comment: @Tomek why do you think so? In the example a `float` is passed to the function and it does compile. Anyhow I made it more explicit by directly calling `drive(0.5f)` in main.

Comment: @Tomek `int` or `double` not, but thats not what OP asked for.

Comment: Apparently I am running on old standard... C++ 17 required. Even C++ 20 for designated initializers.

Comment: @Tomek it will not work when called with something that can be converted to `float`, but thats just the same as with OPs code.