# Switching on a type template

Tags: c++

I have a class in c++ with a class template. I want to know how I can get the type, or do a switch statement on it? I want to do something like this.

```cpp
template <class T>
class Klass {
public:
    Klass() {}
    void get() {
        switch(T) {
            case(int):
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) { ... }`

Comment: It is not possible with a `switch`, but with `if` or `if constexpr` it is possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434491/difference-between-if-constexpr-vs-if

Comment: @RaymondChen is this possible on non primitive classes?

Comment: `std::same_v<T, U>` works for *any* `T` and `U`. They can be user-defined or non-user-defined types

Comment: **Pattern matching** currently works only with `if constexpr`. I don't know about any winning proposals for future, but **Circle** compiler has implemented `as` and `is`; the problem is Circle is closed-source and prvate.

Comment: The odds are relatively high that this is an X/Y problem.  Ie, you have a problem Y.  You dreamed up a solution, but it required you do X.  You then asked "how do I do X"?  It is a good idea when asking such questions to include BOTH X and Y in your wuestion, as often X isn't the "right" way to do Y in the language.

Comment: Isn't template specialization solving part of the issue? So as a template you add the default code path and then specialize the template for the types you want specific behavior.

Comment: For pattern matching in C++26 please bet against it happening here so that the committee members have a better financial incentive to actually vote it in. We all have a voice. https://manifold.markets/MaxPayne/c26-has-pattern-matching ;-)

Comment: @AleixRius before `if constexpr` was introduced, template specialization was the only way to do this, yes.  But not anymore.