# Why does code line give an error even though it never runs?

Tags: c++, templates, ellipsis

I ran into a problem while making another program where there was an error even though the line with the error was never going to run in the first place.

Down below, I have made a simpler version of the program where the same problem occurs.

To summarize the program, I have a class with a constructer that uses ellipsis. When looping through the arguments, I check if each of them are an std::string (I know it's probably inefficient to check each iteration of the loop). If they are std::string, then const char* will be passed to va_arg(), and if not, T will be passed to va_arg(). I did this because I couldn't pass std::string into va_arg(), so I had to do this instead.

The error I get is:

```
 '<function-style-case>': cannot convert from 'const char*' to 'T'
```

Btw, I have commented out the code where T was int and where T was std::string. Only the part where I set T to be double has stayed uncommented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>



template<typename T>
class TestClass {
private:
    T arr[10];

public:
    TestClass(int count, ...) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, count);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (typeid(T) == typeid(std::string))
                arr[i] = T(va_arg(args, const char*)); // This is what causes the error
            else
                arr[i] = va_arg(args, T);
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    /*int int1 = 5;
    int int2 = 7;
    int int3 = 1;
    TestClass<int> intClass(3,
        int1,
        int2,
        int3
    );*/

    /*std::string str1 = "John";
    std::string str2 = "Kim";
    std::string str3 = "Harry";
    TestClass<std::string> stringClass(3,
        str1,
        str2,
        str3
    );*/

    double d1 = 5.12;
    double d2 = 7.56;
    double d3 = 1.89;
    TestClass<double> doubleClass(3,
        d1,
        d2,
        d3
    );
}
```

The code runs perfectly fine when I set T to be int or std::string. However when I set T to be double, the code just won't run. I don't understand this, because the if statement that checks whether or not T is std::string will never be true since T is double. So why does the error occur when the code that gives the error will never run in the first place?

I haven't been able to find anyone with the same problem, and I don't know how to fix it. I would be so happy if you could help me with this issue.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Read about `if constexpr`. Also, don't use C variadics in C++, prefer (much safer) variadic templates.

Comment: All paths in your code must be valid, in all cases. For your use-case I would rather recommend template parameter packs instead of the old C vararg functions. Possibly with specialization for handling literal strings.

Comment: concerning your title: C++ is a compiled language. Whehter or not some code is actually executed at runtime, it will be compiled (even though the compiler may eliminate paths that can be proven to never be taken, they must be valid)

Comment: The expression in an `if()` is evaluated at run time.    So every statement in the `if()` block and the `else` block must be valid, even if you know the expression will be false.    If you want an `if` that is evaluated at *compile time*, and is able to ignore statements, then look up `if constexpr`  (C++11 and later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you should use variadic templates instead of C variadics(aks variadic functions).

---

Now coming to the problem, you can replace the use of `if` with [`constexpr if`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434491/difference-between-if-constexpr-vs-if) and then use `std::is_same` as shown below as [`if constexpr` is evaluated at compile time, whereas `if` is not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43434771/12002570).

```
template<typename T>
class TestClass {
private:
    T arr[10];

public:
    TestClass(int count, ...) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, count);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
//----------vvvvvvvvvvvv------vvvvvvvvvv----------------------->use constexpr if and std::is_same
            if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)  
                arr[i] = T(va_arg(args, const char*)); // compiles now
            else
                arr[i] = va_arg(args, T);
        }
    }
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bzb4rn9Ph)

Comment: @Niocloor You're welcome.