How to make partial specification of a template method of a template class in C++?
I try to make a class method that should execute the part of code only if the static condition is true. Otherwise it shouldn't be executed or even compiled. Below is a simplified variant of the code I try to make:
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

class inet_socket {
    uint32_t ip;
};
class unix_file_socket {
    char path[64];
};

template <typename protocol>
class server
{
public:
    protocol socket;
    void do_something();
};

template <typename protocol>
void server<protocol>::do_something()
{
    /* ... */
    if (std::is_same<protocol, unix_file_socket>::value)
    // use static check if protocol is unix file
    // and if it is then delete file
        std::remove(socket.path);
}

int main()
{
    server<inet_socket> srv;
    srv.do_something();
}


I thought if protocol is not unix_file_socket then the compiler excludes if (false) statement and string std::remove(socket.path) won't be included, so there won't be error of getting field path that is non-existent in non unix_file_socket protocols. But actually I get an error:
file.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void server<protocol>::do_something() [with protocol = inet_socket]’:
file.cpp:33:22:   required from here
file.cpp:27:28: error: ‘class inet_socket’ has no member named ‘path’
   27 |         std::remove(socket.path);
      |                     ~~~~~~~^~~~

Then I tried to make a template method that will have two partial specializations. One will delete file, other won't. Then I'd call only the method that is suitable for the protocol, so it should be the only method that will be compiled for the protocol and the error should not appear. Changes:
template <typename protocol>
class server
{
public:
    protocol socket;
    void do_something();
    template <bool> void remove_socket();
};

template <typename protocol>
void server<protocol>::do_something()
{
    /* ... */
    remove_socket<std::is_same<protocol, unix_file_socket>::value>();
    // static check if protocol is unix file
    // and if it is then use method that deletes file
    // else use method that doesn't
}

template <typename protocol>
template <>
void server<protocol>::remove_socket<true>()
{
    // if socket is unix file
    std::remove(socket.path);
}

template <typename protocol>
template <>
void server<protocol>::remove_socket<false>()
{ /* if it is inet socket do nothing */ }

I had a hope it works, but I got syntax error:
file.cpp:34:11: error: invalid explicit specialization before ‘>’ token
   34 | template <>
      |           ^
file.cpp:34:11: error: enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized
file.cpp:42:11: error: invalid explicit specialization before ‘>’ token
   42 | template <>
      |           ^
file.cpp:42:11: error: enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized

I tried to erase lines template <>, but that didn't work anyway. How to make it work?

if constexpr?

@Evg What do you mean?

I mean if constexpr (std::is_same<protocol, unix_file_socket>::value).

Use if constexpr (condition) { /* statements */ } (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43434771/20785822)

@Evg @Joel Thank you, that worked. That issued the warning warning: ‘if constexpr’ only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’, but that worked.

If you can use C++17, just add that command line flag.

Dupe: explicit specialization of template class member function


template <typename protocol>
template <>
void server<protocol>::remove_socket<true>()


This is simply not allowed (see [temp.expl.spec] p15).
You cannot define an explicit specialization for a member of an unspecialized class.
You could have multiple template <>, but not what you're doing.
The basic issue here is that explicit specializations in C++ work much like non-template entities. I.e. template <> foo<int> works much like foo, except that it has some template syntax around it. template <typename> typename <> is mixing two constructs that don't really work together.
If you are using C++17, you can simply write:
template <typename protocol>
void server<protocol>::do_something()
{
    /* ... */
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<protocol, unix_file_socket>)
        std::remove(socket.path);
}

if constexpr would prevent instantiating std::remove when the condition is false.
See also Difference between "if constexpr()" Vs "if()"
Prior to C++17, you could also define:
template <>
inline void server<unix_file_socket>::do_something()
{
    /* ... */
    std::remove(socket.path);
}

See Template specialization of a single method from a templated class for why we need inline here.
